# Run ES6 import syntax in Node child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, child-process

I officially give up. I'm trying to run a node es6 project that uses es6 import syntax, but the child processes won't work. The problem is that childprocess.fork uses node and not babel-node. I've gotten it to run using babel-node, but now they can't communicate via process.send. I'm looking for any options to solve the problem, maybe there is an easier one.

```
let appPath = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
let babelPath = path.join(appPath, 'node_modules/.bin/babel-node.cmd'); //WINDOWS

let filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'processes', moduleName);
let process = childProcess.fork(filepath, { execPath: babelPath });

process.on('message', msg => console.log(msg));
```

which gives me this:

> Error: channel closed
>       at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:523:16)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've the same problem and it sucks. I don't want to compile since I'm running an engine - so there is no need.

Comment: I used Michals answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Babel CLI page](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) says:

> You should not be using `babel-node` in production.

Instead, compile all the files first, and then run `childProcess.fork()` on the compiled files.

Comment: Child process fork wants a file path to run. If I compile all the files into a build file, how would I fork that code?

Comment: @wayofthefuture Babel doesn't compile all files into one build file. Each file is compiled separately.

Comment: So that means the whole project will be polluted with files of another extension?

Comment: @wayofthefuture Just keep the source files in one directory (for example `src`) and the compiled files in another (for example `build`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess Babel-watch would then be the perfect addition for dev.

Answer (score -1):

In case someone has the same problem. But for test environment such as using mocha. With [this issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2519#issuecomment-251946882) I open on mocha I could solve the problem.

> Running `babel-node node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha test.js` applies by default the compiler to the child process and there is no need to set the `execPath`.
>
> **PS:** Once you run the `mocha` with `babel-node` there is no need to pass `--require` or `--compilers`.